# Поиск самого тяжёлого животного. Найти объект среди нескольких с максимальным значением weight атрибута

Tags: python

Всем привет! 
Не могли бы вы мне помочь?
Есть задача определить самое тяжелое животное  и вывести его вес и имя.

```
class animal:
    weight = 5
    height = 10
    food = None

    def give_food(self, value):
        self.weight += value


class cow(animal):
    name = 'Manka'
    weight = 70
    height = 150
    voice = 'Manka say Muuu'

    def take_milk(self):
        self.weight -= 69.3
        print(self.voice, 'Now we have', self.weight, 'gramm of milk!')


class goose_1(animal):
    weight = 47
    height = 76
    name = "Grey"
    voice = 'Grey Goose say Shhhhhhh'

    def goose_1_voice(self):
        print(self.voice)


class goose_2(goose_1):
    weight = 79
    height = 34
    name = 'White'
    voice = 'White Goose say Shhhhhhh'

    def goose_2_voice(self):
        print(self.voice)


class sheep_1(animal):
    name = 'Sheepy'
    weight = 67
    height = 50
    voice = 'Sheepy say "Beee"'

    def fur(self):
        self.weight -= 63
        print(self.voice, 'Now we have', self.weight, 'kg of fur!')


class sheep_2(sheep_1):
    voice = 'Curly say Yeeeehhh'

    def fur(self):
        self.weight -= 60
        print(self.voice, 'Now we have', self.weight, 'grams of fur!')


class chicken_1(animal):
    name = 'Koko'
    weight = 20
    height = 15
    voice = 'Kokoko'

    def take_eggs(self):
        self.weight -= 3
        print('Koko said', self.voice, 'We took', self.weight, 'of eggs')


class chicken_2(chicken_1):
    name = 'Kukareku'
    voice = "Kokokokoko"

    def take_eggs(self):
        self.weight -= 5
        print(self.name, self.voice, 'We have', self.weight, 'of eggs')



Cow = cow()
Cow.take_milk()
goose_1 = goose_1()
goose_1.goose_1_voice()
goose_2 = goose_2()
goose_2.goose_2_voice()
sheep_1 = sheep_1()
sheep_1.fur()
sheep_2 = sheep_2()
sheep_2.fur()
chicken_1 = chicken_1()
chicken_1.take_eggs()
chicken_2 = chicken_2()
chicken_2.take_eggs()
```

Думаю надо сгенерировать список по значению weight ,а потом отобрать используя функцию max. Головой знаю ,а как написать не понимаю(
На основную часть кода не обращайте внимания, она нужна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from operator import attrgetter

animals = [
    cow(),
    goose_1(),
    goose_2(),
    sheep_1(),
    sheep_2(),
    chicken_1(),
    chicken_2()
]

heaviest = max(animals, key=attrgetter('weight'))
```

Comment: можно и без attrgetter: `heaviest = max(animals, key=lambda x: x.weight)`

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!)

Comment: @GurinArtem [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Боюсь у меня данный код не работает

Comment: @GurinArtem что значит "не работает"? Ошибку выдаёт или выводит неправильные данные?

Comment: Он ничего не выводит.

Comment: можно и без attrgetter: heaviest = max(animals, key=lambda x: x.weight) 
Этот тоже не работает

Comment: @GurinArtem а вы вообще добавили вывод переменной `heaviest`?

Comment: print(heaviest)

Comment: я вас несколько дезинформировал.
Вывод есть: 
<__main__.goose_2 instance at 0x10f9ed0e0>

Тоесть в памяти выделилась ячейка под расчет и инфомация есть ,но она не совсем читабельна.

Comment: Всё логично, в переменной сохранился **объект** с максимальным значением поля `weight`. Так выглядит строковое представление этого объекта. Если хотите что-то более вразумительное, то в классе надо определить метод [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__).

Comment: Вы не могли бы немного пояснить строку
heaviest = max(animals, key=lambda x: x.weight)
я так понимаю мы производим расчет с помощью функции max для переменной hearviest 
В скобках указываем 
- список классов

с ламбдой непонятно(

Comment: Функции `max` надо знать как сравнивать объекты для определения максимального, для этого в параметр `key` передаётся функция возвращающая значение того поля, по которому нужно сравнивать объекты.

Comment: @GurinArtem я уже написал вам выше, как правила ресурса требуют благодарить авторов ответов.

Comment: Где? я не вижую

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: я не понимаю, как вас отблагодарить

Comment: Так вы почитайте [справку сервиса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) или хотя бы потратьте 5 минут на просмотр [обучающего видео](https://youtu.be/PpTqzVGPLQY). Ответы, которые вам помогли, принято [отмечать решением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/204271). Для этого надо нажать на галочку рядом с ответом. Это прибавит вам немного репутации и даст отвечающим мотив помогать вам и дальше.